# DEHUMIDIFIER STAYING AT 75

Tags: dehumidifier

I have a dehumidifier and have it for a few years so I am familiar with how they work.  I have a GE 65pt and it was working fine until today.  The basement is very warm (it is humid outside) and the humidifer is set at 45... it says 75 and won't come.  It has NEVER done this.  I cleaned the filter and unplugged it hoping it would reset. I checked the coils and they are not frozen. 
It keeps running and some water is going in the bucket.   It is about 3 years old etc.  There is nothing blocking the back of it and it is on the carpet but the machine is raised off the carpet. 
I have no idea what is wrong... Please help, can't afford to just toss it and buy a new one...

Comment: what is the actual problem? ... `it says 75 and won't come` is meaningless

Comment: Please edit your question title - check the other questions on here and deal with the all caps.

Answer (score 0):

If some water is going into the bucket that implies it is working, just maybe not as well as it did.  My guess is that over time most of the refrigerant has escaped from the system.  When it was cool in the basement the dehumidifier was able to cool well enough to get below the dew point where water will start to condense out. 
 Now that it is hotter the unit is struggling to get the air cold enough.  Sorry, but I suspect you need to replace or repair the unit.  3 years is a pretty good life, especially if the unit has been running continuously.